# How to use pythons' GeoAlchemy2 to filter on dynamically generated Points?

Tags: python, sql, geoalchemy

I'm trying to do something like this SQL query in Geoalchemy2:

```
SELECT district_polygons.district 
FROM markers, district_polygons 
WHERE ST_Contains(district_polygons.multi_poly, Point(markers.marker_long, markers.marker_lat))
```

This query works great as is in MySQL. This shows me which district each marker is in.

I want to replicate something like this using Geoalchemy2 / SQLAlchemy. This is the what I tried:

```
results = dbSession.query(District_Polygon.district).\
    filter(func.ST_Contains(District_Polygon.multi_poly, WKTElement('POINT({0} {1})'.format(Marker.marker_long, Marker.marker_lat)))).all()
```

Unfortunately the formatter isn't working, and sqlalchemy output looks like this:

```
SELECT district_polygons.district AS district_polygons.district
FROM markers, district_polygons
WHERE ST_Contains(district_polygons.multi_poly, ST_GeomFromText(%s))

INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('POINT(markers.marker_long markers.marker_lat)')
[]
```

How can I replicate the functionality of the SQL command in the ORM model of Geoalchemy / SQLAlchemy? I'd like to avoid raw SQL if I can.